# Execute front end task conditionally depending on which Maven profile is used

Tags: maven, npm, aem, frontend-maven-plugin

we use Maven to deploy code to our Adobe AEM environments. There are different profiles set up in the pom.xml file for different environments (dev or staging). We use the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to execute certain build tasks like compiling css from scss files and minifying js. I want to only run certain executions depending on which profile is called. For example when i run the following command to deploy the code to our Dev1 environment:

```
mvn clean install -PaemDev1
```

I do not want to run the minify-js job because it is a dev environment and it is not needed. But if i run the command to deploy to the aemStaging environment then i do want to run minify-js.

Here is a simplified version of the pom file (i've left out the properties):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<build>
    <resources>
        <!-- a list of stuff -->
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v20.10.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>10.2.3</npmVersion>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/content/ui</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/content/ui</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Compile sass to css</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run compileCss</arguments>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/content/ui</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>minify-js</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run minifyJs</arguments>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/content/ui</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>aemDev1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-package-author</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <targetURL>http://${aem.dev1.author.host}:${aem.dev1.author.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                                <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
                                <userId>${aem.dev1.author.username}</userId>
                                <password>${aem.dev1.author.password}</password>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-package-publish1</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <targetURL>http://${aem.dev1.publish1.host}:${aem.dev1.publish1.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                                <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
                                <userId>${aem.dev1.publish1.username}</userId>
                                <password>${aem.dev1.publish1.password}</password>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>aemStaging</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-package-author</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <targetURL>http://${aem.stg.author.host}:${aem.stg.jenkins.author.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                                <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
                                <userId>${aem.stg.author.username}</userId>
                                <password>${aem.stg.author.password}</password>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Any ideas on how i can do this without having to do major surgery on the pom file? I should probably mention that i am a front end developer and not a Maven expert.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of adding the execution configuration per profile, you can use flags in the maven plugin itself. Then you can run maven passing the true/false values as needed to minify the code. See https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/768